# Concatenating multiple boolean columns to single varchar column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am leveraging PostgreSQL to transform data from one table to another table, and am currently running into a bit of a challenge with boolean columns. I would like to transform a table with boolean values into a single, semicolon delimited varchar field.

Below are the two CREATE TABLE statements that I am executing.

```
CREATE TABLE Color_Table
(
"Id" VARCHAR(255),
"IsRed" BOOL,
"IsOrange" BOOL,
"IsYellow" BOOL,
"IsGreen" BOOL,
"IsBlue" BOOL,
"IsIndigo" BOOL,
"IsViolet" BOOL
)

CREATE TABLE Concatenated_Table
(
"Id" VARCHAR(255),
"Semicolon_Colors" VARCHAR(255)
)
```

Here is a sample row that I am inserting into Color_Table. My expectation would be to transform this into the value: Red; Green; Indigo; Violet;

```
INSERT INTO Color_Table
(
"Id",
"IsRed",
"IsOrange",
"IsYellow",
"IsGreen",
"IsBlue",
"IsIndigo",
"IsViolet"
) 

VALUES
(
'12345_abcd_67890',
true,
false,
false,
true,
false,
true,
true
)
```

I attempted to create a temporary variable by declaring it, and receive an error message. Below is the script / approach that I am attempting to use.

```
DECLARE TempVariable VARCHAR(255);
INSERT INTO Concatenated_Table
    (
        "Id",
        "Semicolon_Colors"
    )
SELECT
colors."Id",
BEGIN
    TempVariable = ''

    IF(colors."IsRed" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Red; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsOrange" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Orange; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsYellow" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Yellow; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsGreen" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Green; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsBlue" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Blue; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsIndigo" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Indigo; ')
    END

    IF(colors."IsViolet" = true)
    BEGIN
        CONCAT(TempVariable, 'Violet; ')
    END
END
FROM Color_Table colors
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated about how to do this!

Comment: But the question is for postgresql or for the other tag....?

Comment: PostgreSQL ideally, though if necessary could be done in MS SQL Server. Would prefer to handle in PostgreSQL to avoid separating it from the existing database.

Comment: It is typically a bad idea any time you want to store multiple values in a single column.  How are you going to query for all rows that are Blue and Yellow, etc...?  In any case, a more traditional approach might be an integer column where you apply bitwise comparisons to determine which colors are on or off.

Comment: @scaisEdge modified, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF both tables exist, though there exists a need to have the data concatenated into a single column

Comment: A better design would be to have a surrogate table with a "Id" and "Color" field that would contain all valid colors for the given ID.  It would be easy to query and allow for additional colors in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The concatenation can be simplified using `concat_ws()` because this takes care of the delimiter `;` and will ignore null values, which means the `case` expressions don't need an explicit `else ''` part:

```
insert into Concatenated_Table ("Id", "Semicolon_Colors")
select "Id", 
       concat_ws('; ', 
          case when "IsRed" then 'Red' end, 
          case when "IsOrange" then 'Red' end, 
          case when "IsYellow" then 'Yellow' end ,
          case when "IsGreen" then 'Green' end,
          case when "IsBlue" then 'Blue' end,
          case when "IsIndigo" then 'Indigo' end,
          case when "IsViolet" then 'Violet' end) 
from Color_Table;
```

If you do need to keep the individual color columns, I would rather create a view with the above `select` statement than copying the data into a new table. The concat and the case statements are very cheap. There is no need to duplicate the data for performance reasons.

---

Unrelated, but: you should really try to avoid quoted identifiers `"IsRead"` they are much more trouble than they are worth it. (But *if* you use them, you should be consistent, your table names don't use quoted identifiers, but your columns do).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried this and @snow_FFFFFF and both work. I also appreciate your remarks re: conventions, it's my first foray into Postgres. My use case is to show a source table vs target table to allow for modification of the target table before ultimately pushing into another database. It's a bit contrived, though I felt more comfortable with approach for the translations required between source and target.

Answer (score 1):

I still think the table design is a bad idea, but you should be able to just concatenate your cases together into a single column - something like this

**UPDATE**: Changed to Postgres syntax from mssql:

```
SELECT
"Id",
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(
  CASE "IsRed" WHEN true THEN 'Red; ' ELSE '' END,
  CASE "IsOrange" WHEN true THEN 'Red; ' ELSE '' END), 
  CASE "IsYellow" WHEN true THEN 'Yellow; ' ELSE '' END),
  CASE "IsGreen" WHEN true THEN 'Green; ' ELSE '' END),
  CASE "IsBlue" WHEN true THEN 'Blue; ' ELSE '' END),
  CASE "IsIndigo" WHEN true THEN 'Indigo; ' ELSE '' END),
  CASE "IsViolet" WHEN true THEN 'Violet; ' ELSE '' END)
  AS Semicolon_Colors
FROM color_table
```

Alternate, cleaner syntax (thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name):

```
SELECT
"Id",    
  CASE WHEN "IsRed" THEN 'Red; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "IsOrange" THEN 'Red; ' ELSE '' END || 
  CASE WHEN "IsYellow" THEN 'Yellow; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "IsGreen" THEN 'Green; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "IsBlue" THEN 'Blue; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "IsIndigo" THEN 'Indigo; ' ELSE '' END ||
  CASE WHEN "IsViolet" THEN 'Violet; ' ELSE '' END
  AS Semicolon_Colors
FROM color_table
```

Comment: SQL (and Postgres) uses `||` to concatenate strings, not `+` and the case can be simplified to `case when isread then 'Red; ' else '' end`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - thanks - was just updating for Postgre - I didn't know about the || operator - that would clean it up nicley

Comment: For Postgres it's not necessary to nest the `concat()` calls. You can use  `concat(case .. end, case ... end, case .. end, ...)`

Comment: Thank you for posting this @snow_FFFFFF, I greatly appreciate your help on this matter. I recognize it's suboptimal, but it's deliberate in nature as the source table has multiple boolean columns, and the target table is a stage for an integration to another database where the architects do not wish to store multiple boolean attributes.